# time-series segmentation in python

Tags: python, time-series, segment

I am trying to segment the time-series data as shown in the figure. I have lots of data from the sensors, any of these data can have different number of isolated peaks region. In this figure, I have 3 of those. I would like to have a function that takes the time-series as the input and returns the segmented sections of equal length.

My initial thought was to have a sliding window that calculates the relative change in the amplitude. Since the window with the peaks will have relatively higher changes, I could just define certain threshold for the relative change that would help me take the window with isolated peaks. However, this will create problem when choosing the threshold as the relative change is very sensitive to the noises in the data.

Any suggestions?

[image: Figure : Desired segmentation of the time-series data]
[image: figure with axes]

Comment: can you post input data? By segment you mean data from beginning of peat to the end of peak? Figure without axis with units has no value.

Comment: Yes, I want the data from start of the peak to the end. I have added the figure with axes. I don’t really know how to add the input data. It is a .txt file. I do not see any options to attach them here.

Comment: You can generate rangom test data with noise to simulate you data. How you need to store this segments of data? in csv ?

Comment: Saving the segments of data is not that important. I just need to find a way to segment them first from the continuous data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you need to find signal out of noise.

1. get mean value of you signal and add some multiplayer that place borders on top and on bottom of noise - green dashed line
2. find peak values below bottom of noise -> array 2 groups of data
3. find peak values on top of noise -> array 2 groups of data
4. get min index of bottom first peak and max index of top of first peak to find first peak range
5. get min index of top second peak and max index of bottom of second peak to find second peak range

Some description in code. With this method you can find other peaks.
One thing that you need to input by hand is to tell program the`x` value between peaks for splitting data into parts.

See graphic for summary.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


# create noise data
def function(x, noise):
    y = np.sin(7*x+2) + noise
    return y

def function2(x, noise):
    y = np.sin(6*x+2) + noise
    return y


noise = np.random.uniform(low=-0.3, high=0.3, size=(100,))
x_line0 = np.linspace(1.95,2.85,100)
y_line0 = function(x_line0, noise)
x_line = np.linspace(0, 1.95, 100)
x_line2 = np.linspace(2.85, 3.95, 100)
x_pik = np.linspace(3.95, 5, 100)
y_pik = function2(x_pik, noise)
x_line3 = np.linspace(5, 6, 100)

# concatenate noise data
x = np.linspace(0, 6, 500)
y = np.concatenate((noise, y_line0, noise, y_pik, noise), axis=0)

# plot data
noise_band = 1.1
top_noise = y.mean()+noise_band*np.amax(noise)
bottom_noise = y.mean()-noise_band*np.amax(noise)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axhline(y=y.mean(), color='red', linestyle='--')
ax.axhline(y=top_noise, linestyle='--', color='green')
ax.axhline(y=bottom_noise, linestyle='--', color='green')
ax.plot(x, y)

# split data into 2 signals
def split(arr, cond):
  return [arr[cond], arr[~cond]]

# find bottom noise data indexes
botom_data_indexes = np.argwhere(y < bottom_noise)
# split by visual x value
splitted_bottom_data = split(botom_data_indexes, botom_data_indexes < np.argmax(x > 3))

# find top noise data indexes
top_data_indexes = np.argwhere(y > top_noise)
# split by visual x value
splitted_top_data = split(top_data_indexes, top_data_indexes < np.argmax(x > 3))

# get first signal range
first_signal_start = np.amin(splitted_bottom_data[0])
first_signal_end = np.amax(splitted_top_data[0])

# get x index of first signal
x_first_signal = np.take(x, [first_signal_start, first_signal_end])
ax.axvline(x=x_first_signal[0], color='orange')
ax.axvline(x=x_first_signal[1], color='orange')

# get second signal range
second_signal_start = np.amin(splitted_top_data[1])
second_signal_end = np.amax(splitted_bottom_data[1])

# get x index of first signal
x_second_signal = np.take(x, [second_signal_start, second_signal_end])
ax.axvline(x=x_second_signal[0], color='orange')
ax.axvline(x=x_second_signal[1], color='orange')

plt.show()
```

**Output:**

red line = mean value of all data

green line - top and bottom noise borders

orange line - selected peak data

[image]

Comment: @AashishShah You're welcome! Will by nice if you accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

1, It depends on how you want to define a "region", but looks like you just have feeling instead of strict definition. If you have a very clear definition of what kind of piece you want to cut out, you can try some method like "matched filter"

2, You might want to detect the peak of absolute magnitude. If not working, try peak of absolute magnitude of first-order difference, even 2nd-order.

3, it is hard to work on the noisy data like this. My suggestion is to do filtering before you pick up sections (on unfiltered data). Filtering will give you smooth peaks so that the position of peaks can be detected by the change of derivative sign. For filtering, try just "low-pass filter" first. If it doesn't work, I also suggest "Hilbert–Huang transform".

*, Looks like you are using matlab. The methods mentioned are all included in matlab.

Comment: The data is from the acceleration sensor. It records the acceleration reading over time. The peak indicate that some force was applied on the sensor at a given time. In the figure above, the load was applied three times with some time delay. This time delay varies with different dataset. So, I want to do some processing individually with each recorded peaks. In order to do that, I have to split them first.